# My test dir looks different from my tutorial and Rails Guides (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, directory

I'm using the book "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" and am going through Chapter 7 which has to do with testing.  The tutorial includes a Product model and has the reader modify the test file `product_test.rb` which apparently should be in `test/models.`  The Railes Guide for tests also has this structure.  Yet for some reason I don't have a models subdirectory in my test directory.  My test directory looks like this:

```
[~/code/depot]:  ls test
fixtures    functional  integration performance test_helper.rb  unit
```

My `product_test.rb` file is in the "unit" folder.

This is causing problems when I try to run tests as demonstrated in the book.  `rake test` works fine as does `ruby -Itest test/unit/product_test.rb`  but `rake test:models` produces the following error:

```
[~/code/depot]:  rake test:models
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'test:models'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't really understand the rake commands but I'm assuming that it's looking for `test/models` when I run `rake test:models`?  At any rate, it doesn't work, and I have no idea why my test directory structure is lacking the models folder and why my `product_test.rb` is in `test/unit` instead.  The Rails Guide on testing also indicates that scaffold-generated models should have tests in `test/models`.  Can anyone explain what may have happened or how I should go about fixing this?

*EDIT*

Output of `rake -T`:

```
[~/code/depot]:  rake -T
rake about              # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
rake assets:clean       # Remove compiled assets
rake assets:precompile  # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
rake db:create          # Create the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current Rails.env (use db:crea...
rake db:drop            # Drops the database using DATABASE_URL or the current Rails.env (use db:drop:all to drop all databases)
rake db:fixtures:load   # Load fixtures into the current environment's database
rake db:migrate         # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false)
rake db:migrate:status  # Display status of migrations
rake db:rollback        # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n)
rake db:schema:dump     # Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR
rake db:schema:load     # Load a schema.rb file into the database
rake db:seed            # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:setup           # Create the database, load the schema, and initialize with the seed data (use db:reset to also drop ...
rake db:structure:dump  # Dump the database structure to db/structure.sql
rake db:version         # Retrieves the current schema version number
rake doc:app            # Generate docs for the app -- also available doc:rails, doc:guides, doc:plugins (options: TEMPLATE=/...
rake log:clear          # Truncates all *.log files in log/ to zero bytes
rake middleware         # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rake notes              # Enumerate all annotations (use notes:optimize, :fixme, :todo for focus)
rake notes:custom       # Enumerate a custom annotation, specify with ANNOTATION=CUSTOM
rake rails:template     # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template) or URL
rake rails:update       # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just update:configs, update:scripts...
rake routes             # Print out all defined routes in match order, with names
rake secret             # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically used to generate a secret for coo...
rake stats              # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application
rake test               # Runs test:units, test:functionals, test:integration together (also available: test:benchmark, test:...
rake test:recent        # Run tests for {:recent=>"test:prepare"} / Test recent changes
rake test:single        # Run tests for {:single=>"test:prepare"}
rake test:uncommitted   # Run tests for {:uncommitted=>"test:prepare"} / Test changes since last checkin (only Subversion and...
rake time:zones:all     # Displays all time zones, also available: time:zones:us, time:zones:local -- filter with OFFSET para...
rake tmp:clear          # Clear session, cache, and socket files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:sessions:clear, tmp:cache:clear, tm...
rake tmp:create         # Creates tmp directories for sessions, cache, sockets, and pids
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake -T` ?

Comment: You have no `rake test:models`, so it doesn't even know about the rake task existing.

Comment: Well, I ended up scrapping the app since I wasn't that far into it.  I started over and this time everything was normal.  Still no idea what I did to mess it up before but at least it's working now. =)

Comment: if you used version control you should be able to do a diff in someway to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like the following in your application.rb?

```
config.generators do |g|
    g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl # if your using factory_girl
    g.test_framework :test_unit, :spec => true, :fixture => false
end
```